# Open XML: Align the text which is indented

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

In the image the second line number(s) text is aligned to 6. instead of according.

[image]

I am writing text into word document using Open XML word processing Document. Whenever I have an indent the text is not aligning properly after the indented number. How to align the text to the first line of text instead aligning to the indent ?

```
Please find the below code

//bullets 6 and 7 text to be written in word document
string value = "6.   According to the latest available equalized assessment roll in the office of the county tax assessor, the assessor's parcel number(s) for the above-mentioned legal description is/are _________, which also include(s) other property.
7.   Appurtenant _________ easement in common with others in accordance with the terms and conditions relative to the use thereof.";
//bookmark
string name = "COMEXCEPTIONS";
string[] newLineArray = { Environment.NewLine, "\n" };
 var bookMark = Document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().Where(bm => bm.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == name);
foreach (BookmarkStart bm in bookMark)
                    {
                        if (bm.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == name.ToUpper())
                        {
                            var textReplacementPending = true;
                            Run sib = bm.NextSibling<Run>();
                            if (sib == null)
                            {
                                bool isEmptyField = false; 
                                if (!IsFormFiled)
                                {
                                    isEmptyField = name.Equals(value);
                                }

                                WordToolKitExtension wd = new WordToolKitExtension();
                                wd.SetBookmarkText(bm, value, !isEmptyField);
                            }


                            while (textReplacementPending && sib != null)
                            {

                                var fieldChars = sib.Descendants<FieldChar>();
                                foreach (FieldChar fieldChar in fieldChars)
                                {

                                    if (fieldChar.FieldCharType == FieldCharValues.Separate)
                                    {
                                        if (!IsFormFiled)
                                        {
                                            RunProperties runProperties17 = new RunProperties();
                                            Color color10 = new Color() { Val = "FF0000" };
                                            runProperties17.Append(color10);
                                            sib.Append(runProperties17);
                                        }

                                        Text text12 = new Text();
                                        if (name.ToUpper() == POLICY_DAY.ToUpper() ||
                                            name.ToUpper() == POLICY_MONTH.ToUpper())
                                            text12.Text = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.ToUpper() : value;
                                        else
                                        {
                                            text12.Text = value;
                                        }



                                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Split(newLineArray, StringSplitOptions.None).Count() <= 1)
                                        {
                                            sib.Append(text12);
                                            try
                                            {

                                                OpenXmlElement elem = sib.NextSibling();
                                                //if (sib.Descendants<OpenXmlElement>() != null)
                                                //    k = sib.Descendants<OpenXmlElement>().Count();
                                                while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
                                                {
                                                    OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();

                                                    if (nextElem.ChildElements.Count > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        elem.Remove();
                                                        elem = nextElem;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        return;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception ex)
                                            {

                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                                                ParseForOpenXML(ref sib, value);
                                        textReplacementPending = false;
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                sib = sib.NextSibling<Run>();
                                if (sib == null)
                                    return;

                            }
                        }
                    }



public void ParseForOpenXML(ref Run run, string textualData)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] newLineArray = { Environment.NewLine, "\n" };
                string[] textArray = textualData.Split(newLineArray, StringSplitOptions.None);
                bool first = true;
                foreach (string line in textArray)
                {
                    if (!first)
                    {
                        run.Append(new Break());
                    }

                    first = false;

                    Text txt = new Text();
                    txt.Text = line;
                    run.Append(txt);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce] - there's too much code here which has nothing to do with the problem. FWIW you need to break the numbered sections down into separate `Paragraph` elements. Then you need to specify `ParagraphProperties` for these paragraphs and append to them `Indentation` objects with the specifications (you need a hanging indent). See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.indentation.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraphproperties.aspx.

Comment: It's also helpful to create the content you require in Word then investigate the document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. That generates the basic code to create the document.

Comment: Hi Cindy, I tried with Hanging indent it didn't work. I am not doing something right! If I have a numbered list paragraph, for example 1. some para 2. second para 3. Third para Now my requirement is to add 4th para and hence forth through the c# open xml code and prefix the fouth para with the next number 4. and also align the text as shown in the image and copy previous paragraph formatting as well. Possible for me to have a sample code or any references to go through ? Thank you

Comment: My second comment, about using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool, is what you have to do. And for the document, type in a few short paragraphs, select them all, and apply Word's numbering using the "Mulilevel list" button: Home tab, Paragraphs group in the Ribbon. The numbering and the indentation will be automatic - they're built into Word in the form of *styles*.